# Can't access to express server on AWS using HTTP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

To get acquainted with node ,AWS and web hosting in general I decided to  create a simple web app hosted on a node/express server and then try to host it on an AWS instance.

I have my app running locally on my machine , here is the server.js code :

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const port = 80;
const app = express();
const compiler =webpack(config);

app.use(express.static('dist'))

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler,{
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    open('http://localhost:' + port);
  }
});
```

But when I try deploying and running it on an AWS instance I can't seem to access the running node server,

Here are the steps that I follow:

### 1.  To launch the AWS instance I choose Amazon Linux instance[image]

### 2.For the security rule this are the inbound rules I apply : [image]

### 3. I SSH into my instance ,install node and  then git to get my app from github

### 4. This is how my home/ec2-user/testRep folder looks like after I have cloned my repositary and installed the node dependencies:[image]

### 5. I run the server using `npm start`

### 6.The server seems to start without any issues:

[image]

But when I go the public DNS as   for the instance using a browser , I get site not found

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you verify that you create your in instance in a public network? Does it have a public IP? Are you running your nodeJS server as 0.0.0.0:80?

Comment: If you are using web pack try to put at the end the start command: --host 0.0.0.0. The start command should look like -> webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --host 0.0.0.0. (replace de dev servers for prod depending on your environment)

Comment: Public (Elastic) IP not required as AWS generates FQDN and port 80 is used. Try testing with telnet `telnet xxx.ec2domainanme 80` to see if you get through.

Comment: I tried telneting through puty , seem like it gives 'connection refused'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deploying in localhost, in your listen function you should put something like:

```
app.listen(port, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    open('http://0.0.0.0:' + port);
  }
});
```

Also don't forget to running it with all the permissions (usually the port 80 needs greater permissions, like root)

Comment: that didn't seem to change anything :(

Comment: when you are inside the machine and you  make a wget to the IP, does it works?

Comment: sorry doing this ,I can't run my server on that port, I get an EACCES error

Comment: I got it running now , I had to run using the on the 0.0.0.0 port using Root access, 

can you append "and run 'sudo npm start' to as root" and then i can accept your answer

Comment: So it's possible that something else is running over there. Try to run your server in a different port and let me know